# While joining 2 tables, can i use *?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
Select * from hospital,favorite
Where hospital.h_id=favorite.h_id AND favorite.u_id=$uid;
```

Is this query valid? 
I mean, while joining 2 tables can i select all records from both tables by using `*`?

Comment: In mysql you can, are you using mysql or sql-server? I think sql-server supports that as well though. Why don't you try it?

Comment: `*` means `all columns`... it should work in theory but it's like getting all the columns but ended up using some of them.. on the other hand avoid using old `joining` methods...

Comment: Yes but it's best practice to list your columns.  And often necessary if there are duplicate column names in both tables and you need to reference one of those columns specifically later on. (For instance `h_id`)

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You CAN, but SHOULD NOT

Comment: You should use ANSI Joins, not the comma with where... SELECT * FROM Hospital h INNER JOIN favorite f ON h.id = f.id WHERE f.u_id = $uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, by the SQL specification `*` means "all columns".

The result of your SQL will have all columns of both tables. In this result some columns may have the same name (if they exist on both tables) and that's OK.

If you want to differentiate columns with the same name, you can assign an alias to each specific column. However, to do this you won't be using `*` anymore but the full list of columns.